# United States City/State comprehensive database

Tags: data, united-states

I have been searching online for a comprehensive record of all Cities by State in the United States.  When I searched I found some dead links to old data sets.

Where is the best place to find such a record online?

Comment: How do you define a "comprehensive record"?  I recommend that you use the edit button to revise your Question with more precise details of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The US Board of Geographic Names is the authority for placenames in the United States.  Their website has [domestic and Antarctic data](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm) while NGA distributes [international data](http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.htm).  The formats of the files on each site are documented.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) with over 8 million place names to download.

Comment: GeoNames is an international database